# Stop exp from switching to LAN URL when tunneling

Tags: react-native, expo

When trying to run `exp start --tunnel` in a react-native project, I often see the warning:

> 22:15:31 [exp] Your URL is: exp://192.168.200.83:19000
>
> ....
>
> 22:15:31 [exp] Switched to a LAN URL because the tunnel appears to be down. Only devices in the same network can access the app. Restart with `exp start --tunnel` to try reconnecting.

This is a problem since none of my devices or the AVD can connect to this URL to download the project.

The problem does not seem to related to any firewall settings as it does not occur every time (just very consistently). When the error does not happen, I get a URL that I can work with that looks like:

> 22:44:38 [exp] Your URL is: exp://en-ux3.myexpousername.myapp.exp.direct:80

Is there something that can be done about this to get it to stop switching? What causes this switching exactly? Is there some way to get devices to be able to use this URL instead (I have an android device connected to same wifi, but seems to be unable to download the project from the LAN URL)?

** Totally new to react-native and expo, so if I am missing evidence of any common debugging steps for this kind of problem, please let me know what they may be in the comments so I can update the question.

**UPDATE**:

A similar question to this is addressed in the expo forums: https://forums.expo.io/t/switched-to-a-lan-url-because-the-tunnel-appears-to-be-down-only-devices-in-the-same-network-can-access-the-app-you-can-restart-the-project-to-try-reconnecting/4483.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the message
`Switched to a LAN URL because the tunnel appears to be down. Only devices in the same network can access the app. You can restart the project to try reconnecting.`
And I've solved it closing Visual Studio (then pressing the Restart button from Expo XDE)